# DOM not validating form

Tags: javascript, python, flask, dom

DOM is driving me crazy! I did everything right but still not working. I am trying to validate form in Jinja via DOM or Javascript using innerHTML before submitting the form in flask. I know I am doing the right thing but the div doesn't change. I need your help guys. What am I doing wrong ?

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
                    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form">
                <fieldset>
                <legend> <h5>{{ legend }} </h5></legend>
                     {{ form.hidden_tag() }} 

                      <div class="form-group">
                      {{ form.course_name.label(for="name") }}<br>
                      {% if form.course_name.errors %}
                        {% for error in form.course_name.errors %}

                            {{ form.course_name(size=100, class="form-control", id="name", placeholder="Enter course name") }}<br>
                            <span style="color: red;">{{ error }}</span>
                            <h1 id="nameeee" style="color: red;"></h1>

                        {% endfor %}   
                      {% else %}
                          {{ form.course_name(size=100, class="form-control", id="name", placeholder="Enter course name") }}<br>
                      {% endif %}   
                      
                      </div>


                      <p>
                      {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary", id="submit") }}
                      
                      </p>

 </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const name_course = document.getElementById('name');
    const submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    const name = document.getElementById('nameeee')
    



    submit.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        
        if (name_course.value.length < 1){
          name.textContent = "Name must not be empty";
          alert(name_course.value.length);
      };
        
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did not work because the h1 was placed inside the loop. So I had to take the h1 out of the loop.

```
<h1 id="nameeee" style="color: red;"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on what you mean by `right thing but the div doesn't change.` Please expand on this in the comments if the proposed solution below doesn't solve the problem.

I believe in this case the `jinja` HTML render

```
{{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary", id="submit") }}
```

does not achieve the purpose of submitting the form to the back-end. It's is not equivalent to having a `submit` button, as so

```
<button type="submit"> Send </button>
```

that performs the method and action set on your opening `form` tag. Try with this `<p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>` and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to validate using javascript before submitting in flask but the javascript i wrote is not validating

Comment: Use `jQuery` in an external JS file. This will check it asynchronously compared to a vanilla JS approach. You can research on this and should surely solve your problem.

Comment: If this answer helped in your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information